# How do I stop input type text from executing html code

Tags: html, database, alignment

I use a system on creating and then querying the data form the db into a table.The problem is that if I write for example `<h1>test</h1>`, the table executes it as a html code.

How can I stop it from executing the code, just querying as simple text.

Comment: BTW: HTML is not "executed", it is merely interpreted and displayed by the browser.

Comment: What server side language are you using? The will allow a more contextually useful answer, beyond the concepts at a higher (non language specific) level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to sanitize the input on the server before using. This is also important to prevent SQL injection attacks.

How you do this depends on which server-side language you're using.

For PHP,

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

See: http://www.bitrepository.com/sanitize-data-to-prevent-sql-injection-attacks.html

Answer (score 0):

You should change some characters in your html so it'll not be recognized by browser as html. For php `htmlspecialchars()` will fit your purpose ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php ).
P.S. Hope you do validation of input before inserting it to DB.